# Redis 4.5.1 - hanging in NodeJS 18

Tags: node.js, redis

Can someone advise on how to make this run successfully?
I did "npm install redis" which should be using this: https://github.com/redis/node-redis

My package.json has     "redis": "^4.5.1","node-redis": "^0.1.7",...
and I'm running nodeJS V 18 on my Windows 10 computer.
Once I get it working there, I want to add it to my Serverless/React application,
and run it on AWS Lambda.

The code is based on this example: https://github.com/cypherkunp/nodejs-101/blob/fef7e2b2717617e80333dbfded74717b52df1d80/4-npm-modules/redis/index.js#L4
Other research said with Redis 4 and later, you have to do the connect. Prior to adding that I was getting a "connection closed" error.

I think it's going to need awaits or promises or something, but the example above certainly didn't have all that.

I can use the same redis server with no issues in Python (5 minutes, vs 4 hours of putzing with NodeJs).

```
    const redis = require('redis');
    const REDIS_RELATIX_HOST = "redis-xxxxxc277.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com"
    const REDIS_RELATIX_PORT =  "12345"
    const REDIS_RELATIX_PASSWORD = "mypass"
    
    
async function runRedis() {

    const redisClient = redis.createClient({
        socket: {
            host: REDIS_RELATIX_HOST,
            port: REDIS_RELATIX_PORT
        },
            password: REDIS_RELATIX_PASSWORD 
        }) 
    await redisClient.connect();        
    console.log("redisClient.isOpen: " + redisClient.isOpen)
    redisClient.on('error', err => {
        console.log('Error ' + err);
    });

    console.log("Try set hello")
    redisClient.set('hello', 'world');

    // nested hashes
    console.log("Try hSet nested hashes")
    redisClient.hSet('spanish', 'red', 'rojo');
    redisClient.hSet('spanish', 'orange', 'naranja');
    redisClient.hSet('spanish', 'blue', 'azul');

    redisClient.hSet('german', 'red', 'rot');
    redisClient.hSet('german', 'orange', 'orange');
    redisClient.hSet('german', 'blue', 'blau');
    console.log("Done with hSets nested hashes")

    console.log("Try to .get 'hello' ")
    redisClient.get('hello', (err, value) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(value);
    });

    console.log("Try to .get 'spanish/red' ")
    redisClient.hGet('spanish', 'red', (err, value) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(value);
    });
}

console.log("Start")
runRedis();
console.log("The end")
```

This is the results from the Windows Command window, and then it hangs and doesn't finish.

```
Start
The end
redisClient.isOpen: true
Try set hello
Try hSet nested hashes
Done with hSets nested hashes
Try to .get 'hello'
Try to .get 'spanish/red'
```

This is a variation using an async function (everything exce

```
const redis = require('redis');
const REDIS_RELATIX_HOST = "redis-xxxxxc277.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com"
const REDIS_RELATIX_PORT =  "12345"
const REDIS_RELATIX_PASSWORD = "mypass"

async function runRedis() {

    const redisClient = redis.createClient({
        socket: {
            host: REDIS_RELATIX_HOST,
            port: REDIS_RELATIX_PORT
        },
            password: REDIS_RELATIX_PASSWORD 
        }) 

   
    console.log("redisClient.isOpen: " + redisClient.isOpen)
    redisClient.on('error', err => {
        console.log('Error ' + err);
    });
    await redisClient.connect();        

    console.log("Try set hello")
    await redisClient.set('hello', 'world');

    // nested hashes
    console.log("Try hSet nested hashes")
    await redisClient.hSet('spanish', 'red', 'rojo');
    await redisClient.hSet('spanish', 'orange', 'naranja');
    await redisClient.hSet('spanish', 'blue', 'azul');

    await redisClient.hSet('german', 'red', 'rot');
    await redisClient.hSet('german', 'orange', 'orange');
    await redisClient.hSet('german', 'blue', 'blau');
    console.log("Done with hSets nested hashes")

    console.log("Try to .get 'hello' ")
    await redisClient.get('hello', (err, value) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(value);
    });

    console.log("Try to .get 'spanish/red' ")
    await redisClient.hGet('spanish', 'red', (err, value) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(value);
    });
}

console.log("Start")
runRedis();
console.log("The end")
```

Results:

```
Start
redisClient.isOpen: false
The end
Try set hello
Try hSet nested hashes
Done with hSets nested hashes
Try to .get 'hello'
Try to .get 'spanish/red'
^C
```

I took the same code, and put it in another file and changed it to "ioredis" ("^5.2.5").  NOTE: I don't yet want to use ioredis, because webpack5 gives me issues with that when I try to deploy to AWS, and that will be another issue to work out.

It showed the following.  Note that is shows a local 127.0.0.1 connection which is not what I was trying to connect to.

```
Start
redisClient.isOpen: undefined
Try set hello
Try hSet nested hashes
Done with hSets nested hashes
Try to .get 'hello'
Try to .get 'spanish/red'
The end
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\GitHub\Relatix\Apps\CMS_Bad2\node_modules\ioredis\built\redis\event_handler.js:175:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:320:12)
MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\GitHub\Relatix\Apps\CMS_Bad2\node_modules\ioredis\built\redis\event_handler.js:175:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:320:12)
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\GitHub\Relatix\Apps\CMS_Bad2\node_modules\ioredis\built\redis\event_handler.js:175:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:320:12)

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Here's an update on the above.  The connection is quite different with ioredis. (No .connect method needed).  This connection worked; we just pass the three parms, rather than have the socket/password substructures:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
        host: REDIS_RELATIX_HOST,
        port: REDIS_RELATIX_PORT,
        password: REDIS_RELATIX_PASSWORD 
    })
```

Now the ioredis version does display the value, but then hangs:

```
Try set hello
Try hSet nested hashes
Done with hSets nested hashes
Try to .get 'hello'
Try to .get 'spanish/red'
The end
world
rojo
^C
```

Even this example, when I run it in my project hangs after setting and retrieving the data:
https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/main/examples/string.js

```
Bob
20
[ 'Bob', '20', 'I am a programmer' ]
0
21
1000
^C
```

Also a side question, why does it make me enter redisClient.hGet instead of redisClient.hget.  I get function not found on just the .hget, but I see many other people using it in their examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there and certainly on the right path!

The example you are working from uses an earlier version of Node Redis. With Node Redis 4.0, several breaking changed were introduced. The biggest feature added was support for Promises and elimination of the need for any callbacks. All the methods were also renamed to be either camel-cased—`hSet`, `hGetAll`, `sIsMember`—or uppercased—`HGET`, `HGETALL`, `SISMEMBER`.

ioredis is an entirely separate library with its own API. It is not a simple matter of just swapping out one for the other. So that comes with its own can of worms. Based on what you've said, I would avoid it.

Also, Node.js 18 supports top-level awaits and ESM-style imports. So this code can be tidies up. Using the sample code you are looking at could be rewritten for all the aforementioned version of this as:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis'

// connect to Redis
const redis = createClient('redis://localhost:6379')
redis.on('error', err => console.log('Error ' + err))
await client.connect()

// set a string
await client.set('hello', 'world')

// set some hash fields
await client.hSet('spanish', 'red', 'rojo')
await client.hSet('spanish', 'orange', 'naranja')
await client.hSet('spanish', 'blue', 'azul')

// another way of setting hash fields this
await client.hSet('german', {
  red:, 'rot',
  orange:, 'orange',
  blue: 'blau'
})

// get a string
const hello = await client.get('hello')

// get a hash field
const red = await client.hGet('spanish', 'red')
console.log("red in Spanish=" + red); 

// get all the hash fields
const german = await client.hGetAll('german')
await redisClient.disconnect(); // needs this line to not hang
```

It's also worth noting that you can get a performance boost by only awaiting you last call that mutates the state of Redis. This will result in them all being "[pipelined](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/)".

```js
// set a string
client.set('hello', 'world')

// set some hash fields
client.hSet('spanish', 'red', 'rojo')
client.hSet('spanish', 'orange', 'naranja')
await client.hSet('spanish', 'blue', 'azul')
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a little confused.  What did you really change?  You changed the requires to an import, and added an await on the connect.  What about my async function, and calling the async funtion from outside it?

Comment: The `await` on the `.connect` pretty important. If you don't have it, Redis will issue a bunch of commands before you actually have a connection. And the error handling needs to happen before you connect or you won't get an error if the all to `.connect` has problem. I also removed the callback on `.get` and `.hGet` and simply awaited their response as I don't believe Node Redis 4.x supports callbacks anymore. Could be wrong on that point but it's still tidier.

Comment: I removed the wrapping function as Node 18 doesn't need it—it supports top-level awaits. But if you want to add it back, that's not a problem. Just wrap most of what I wrote in athe `runRedis` function and make sure it's marked `async`.

Comment: I'm getting this: SyntaxError: "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" - which is why I used an async function.  To you have "type": "module" in your package.json?  Can I do it without module?  I'm on V18.13.0.   Also, I get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" if I use import instead of require - so you must be using modules???  Something hidden going on beside the raw code?

Comment: If you put that code in `server.js` in a Node.js project with "type": "module" in the `package,json` it should work when you run `npm start`.

Comment: Did as you said.  But, maybe because I'm using the remote Redis server, but I learned that I have to include "redisClient.disconnect()";  or "await redisClient.disconnect()";  for the NodeJS not to hang when I run it.

Comment: Yep. You'll need that. I prefer to call `.quit` instead as it tells Redis that the client is done while `.disconnect` just drops the connection and sometimes Redis takes a bit of time to clean up those abandoned connections.